# How to update process instance variables?

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm using Camunda Java Api, and i would like to change a process instance variable for a running process, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. If you set a variable in a java delegate, it overwrites the previous value(if any).

Comment: but java delegate must be called from a task service. my question is about updating existing variable for all process instance without updating process definition.

Comment: There's a rest API for variable modification: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/process-instance/variables/post-variables/
So you can check the sources of `ProcessInstanceResourceImpl.modifyProcessInstance` to see what's going on... basically `runtimeService.createProcessInstanceModification(processInstanceId) and then some more code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally, find out how to update a variable for all running process instance :

```
List<ProcessInstance> processInstances =
            runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
                    .processDefinitionKey(processKey)
                    .active()
                    .list();
    processInstances.forEach(processInstance -> {
        List<Execution> executions = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery()
                .processInstanceId(processInstance.getId())
                .list();
        executions.forEach(execution -> {
            runtimeService.setVariable(execution.getId(), variableName, variableValue);
        });
    });
```

Comment: How do you execute this code ? Do you expose it as a REST endpoint ?

Answer (score 4):

The RuntimeService has a method ‘setVariable’ which can be called with processInstanceId, variableName and value.

You can finde the processInstance by using ‘runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()....’, for example by using the process business key.